# How to set form_validation error messages for 3 different languages in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I'm thinking about duplicating the system\english\form_validation_lang.php file or folder, but I don't know how could I work that out.

Answer (score 1):

For new languages, you should just create a new **form_validation_lang.php** file inside each language folder, like:

> application/language/portugues/form_validation_lang.php
>
> application/language/espanol/form_validation_lang.php
>
> application/language/french/form_validation_lang.php

Then, you just have to set the appropriate language and Codeigniter will fetch the translations according to the language set.

More information can be found in the [Codeigniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html)